# Parsing json which contains string with spaces using jq

Tags: json, sh, jq

I have a json as :

```
{"message":["Another open merge request already exists for this source branch: !5193"]}
```

I want to you use jq in a shell script and check whether this string is there or not .

The string i want to search is `Another open merge request already exists for this source branch`

I am trying it via command :

```
cat temp.json| jq --arg MESSAGE "$MESSAGE" | select(.message == Another open merge request already exists for this source branch)
```

When attempting to run the jq command, it has this error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end
```

Any suggestions where its going wrong

Comment: You need quotes around strings in `jq`, like in most languages.
`jq 'select(.message == "Another open merge request already exists for this source branch")' temp.json` fixes another couple of syntax errors as well as the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score -1):

`cat temp.json | jq --arg MESSAGE "$MESSAGE" 'any(.message[];startswith($MESSAGE))'`

i think you passed the argument wrongly, this should help to do the trick

this will return true or false depends on whether the string is found or not